# when I'm trying to open file in vi mode its prompting help.txt, How to resolve this issue

Tags: vi

When I'm trying to open file in vi mode its prompting help.txt as shown below. I tried to close it by using :q, for few seconds its closing again im getting help.txt. i;m not able to edit my file. recently i;m facing this issue. can any one help me on this

> *help.txt*      For Vim version 7.2.  Last change: 2008 Jul 21
>
> ```
>         VIM - main help file
>                                                          k
> ```
>
> Move around:  Use the cursor keys, or "h" to go left,            h
>   l
>                   "j" to go down, "k" to go up, "l" to go right.       j
>
> Close this window:  Use ":q".    Get out of Vim:  Use
>   ":qa!" (careful, all changes are lost!).
>
> Jump to a subject:  Position the cursor on a tag (e.g. |bars|) and hit
>   CTRL-].    With the mouse:  ":set mouse=a" to enable the mouse (in
>   xterm or GUI).
>                       Double-click the left mouse button on a tag, e.g. |bars|.
>           Jump back:  Type CTRL-T or CTRL-O (repeat to go further back).
>
> Get specific help:  It is possible to go directly to whatever you want
>   help
>                       on, by giving an argument to the |:help| command.
>                       It is possible to further specify the context:
>                                                           *help-context*
>                             WHAT                  PREPEND    EXAMPLE      ~
>                         Normal mode command      (nothing)   :help x
>                         Visual mode command         v_       :help v_u
>                         Insert mode command         i_       :help i_
>                         Command-line command        :        :help :quit
>                         Command-line editing        c_       :help c_
>                         Vim command argument        -        :help -r

Comment: So you're saying that when you try to open a file other than help.txt, instead help.txt opens in VI? What file are you trying to open? Do you know that it's actually there and contains content?

Comment: When i tried to open file1.sh or test.csv in vi mode im getting help.txt with some content as shown above. I;m not able to do any changes in file

Comment: How did you create those files? What sort of content are you expecting inside? What is the exact command you're using to open the file in Vi?

Comment: by using vi mode i created all the shell scripts and by using vi file.sh im opening the file to edit the script. but its not allowing me to do any changes...... when i open the file in vi mode immediately its prompting help.txt content